# How do I transfer suiteCRM file from one server to another

Tags: migration

I have a site in server xxx, which is slow so I need to transfer it to a server yyy. It is a suiteCRM. So how do I migrate this to the new server , it needs to be a suiteCRM.

Answer (score 1):

Since SuiteCRM is an open-source fork of SugarCRM, the procedure to copy a Suite server is similar to Sugar. The instructions for moving a SugarCRM server are here:
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/Platform_Management/Moving_Sugar_to_Another_Server/index.html

Here's the process I followed to successfully shift a SuiteCRM installation from one Linux/MySQL server to another:

(NB. Do all of the following with super-user privileges, i.e. either login as root, use the sudo command, or prefix all the commands with sudo.)

1. Set up the new server with all the pre-requisites needed for SuiteCRM. For Debian, these were the commands:

   ```
   apt-get install apache2
   apt-get install mysql-client
   apt-get install mysql-server
   apt-get install php5
   apt-get install php5-mysql
   ```

   Make sure you use a strong password for the MySQL root user, and keep a note of it somewhere. It doesn't have to be the same passsword you used on the original SuiteCRM server.

   Specify Apache as the web server to reconfigure automatically.
2. Set up an Apache Virtual Host to point to the location you want to run SuiteCRM. This is exactly the same as setting up a Virtual Host for any website .. the process is well-documented elsewhere.

   The webtree for SuiteCRM is the directory you specify using the Apache DocumentRoot directive. I made sure the webtree was the same on the new server as it was on the old, although it may work if you shift it.
3. If your original SuiteCRM installation had a session directory, create this directory on the new server and make sure that the www-data user is able to write to it. E.g.:

   ```
   mkdir /var/www/suitecrm-session-directory
   chown www-data /var/www/suitecrm-session-directory
   ```

   The session directory must be in the same location as the directory on the old SuiteCRM server, or else you'll need to find and update the SuiteCRM configuration parameter that points to it.
4. Copy across all the files in the webtree on the old SuiteCRM server to the new. I used rsync for this. In the following example, the webtree was /var/www/suitecrm on both the old and new servers.

   First make sure rsync is installed on both the old and new servers using:

   ```
   apt-get install rsync
   ```

   Then log into the new webserver and run the following (replace "root" with the user you log in as on the old server, and "oldserver.com" with the URL of the old server):

   ```
   cd /var/www/suitecrm
   rsync -avg -e ssh root@oldserver.com:/var/www/suitecrm .
   ```

   You'll be prompted for the user password unless you've got certificate-based SSH authentication set up.
5. Log in to the old SuiteCRM server and take a copy of the database. You'll need to know the MySQL database root user password (replace "suitecrm" with the actual name of the SuiteCRM database on the old server):

   ```
   mysqldump --user=root --password=theactualpassword suitecrm >suitecrmdump.sql
   ```
6. Copy the database dump that you've just created across to the new server. I used scp for this. Log in to the new server and run the following (replace "root" with the user you log in as on the old server, and "oldserver.com" with the URL of the old server):

   ```
   scp root@oldserver.com:~/suitecrmdump.sql .
   ```
7. Create the database on the new server and import the data from the database dump. NB. You'll need to keep the database name the same - if not, then you'll need to find and update the SuiteCRM configuration parameter that points to this. Carry out the following on the new server:

   ```
   mysql --user=root --password=theactualpassword
   ```

   From the mysql prompt:

   ```
   create database suitecrm;
   exit
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   mysql --user=root --password=theactualpassword suitecrm <suitecrmdump.sql
   ```
8. Create the MySQL database users that SuiteCRM will use to access the database.

   First log in to the old database server and run:

   ```
   mysql --user=root --password=theactualpassword
   ```

   From the mysql prompt:

   ```
   SELECT Host,User from mysql.user;
   ```

   This will display a list of database users. Two of them will be SuiteCRM users - one on localhost, the other on the SuiteCRM installation's public URL.

   Type the following to exit MySQL:

   ```
   exit
   ```

   Log in to the new database server and run:

   ```
   mysql --user=root --password=theactualpassword
   ```

   From the mysql prompt (replace "suitecrmuser" and "suitehost.com" with the actual users and hosts you noted down from the old server. Also use the same SuiteCRM database user password that was used in the old server, or else you'll need to find and update the relevant configuration parameter in SuiteCRM. This may be different from the database root user's password):

   ```
   CREATE USER 'suitecrmuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   CREATE USER 'suitecrmuser'@'suitehost.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   ```
9. Make a copy of the access rights for the SuiteCRM users:

   First log in to the old database server and run:

   ```
   mysql --user=root --password=theactualpassword
   ```

   From the mysql prompt:

   ```
   SHOW GRANTS FOR 'suitecrmuser'@'localhost';
   SHOW GRANTS FOR 'suitecrmuser'@'suitehost.crm';
   ```

   Copy the grants that appear to a text editor. Remove the pipe symbols from the start and end of the lines. The grants for each user consist of two lines of SQL code beginning with GRANT USAGE ON.

   Type the following to exit MySQL:

   ```
   exit
   ```
10. Apply the access rights to the users on the new server:

    Log in to the new database server and run:

    ```
    mysql --user=root --password=theactualpassword
    ```

    At the mysql prompt, paste in the lines of SQL beginning with GRANT USAGE ON, for each of the two database users. There should be four lines all up. Add a semi-colon to the end of each line. Press Enter on each line to run the SQL code and apply the rights.

    Type the following to exit MySQL:

    ```
    exit
    ```
11. Copy over the SuiteCRM crontab entry from the old server to the new.

    First log in to the old server and run:

    ```
    crontab -l
    ```

    This will list the crontab entries on the server. There should be an entry for SuiteCRM's regular cron task, which runs every minute. Copy this line to a text editor.

    Then log in to the new server and run:

    ```
    crontab -e
    ```

    This will open the cron table on the new server in edit mode. Paste in the SuiteCRM crontab entry. Exit and save - to do this on Debian Linux, press Ctrl-X and answer Yes to the prompt that appears.
12. Test everything thoroughly to make sure it works.

    Using a test workstation, edit the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file to set your SuiteCRM server's URL to point to the new server. Make sure it's working correctly before cutting over the DNS. Remove the hosts file entries after the testing is completed.
13. Cut over the DNS, using your DNS nameserver service. Edit the zonefile to point the URL of your Suite server to the IP address of the new server.